# Non-Local Connection to Azure Cosmos DB Emulator with SSL

Tags: ssl, azure-cosmosdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm attempting to connect to Azure Cosmos DB Emulator from a non-local machine (technically it's WSL on the same machine, but practically WSL is connecting to another IP than localhost).

I'm running the emulator with `/AllowNetworkAccess` to allow non-local connections. I've also run it with `/GenCert=<IP>` to generate a new certificate for the visible IP address. And I can connect with SSL validation disabled in my program. However, I don't want to disable SSL validation to avoid accidentally releasing with SSL validation disabled (or more realistically, having to constantly re-disable it locally since I could never get a PR with it disabled accepted).

However, when requiring SSL validation with the cert generated with `/GenCert` I get the following error

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
```

I've followed [Microsoft's instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#import-certificate) to install the generated certificate.

How can I connect to Azure Cosmos DB Emulator when not connecting to localhost with SSL?

I've also tried the Docker version of the emulator, but that corrupts my DB not long after I start using it.